# Enum not correctly generated in Q file with queryDSL and play framwork

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, querydsl

I just created a new project with activator and playJava.

My build.sbt :

```
import play.sbt.PlayImport._
name := """querdsl"""
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava,QueryDSLPlugin)
queryDSLPackage := "models"
scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  javaJpa,
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.10.Final"
)
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

My plugins.sbt :

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.2")
// Web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.code-troopers.play" % "play-querydsl" % "0.1.2")
```

I created just one model :

```
package models;

import enums.Status;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="User")
public class User {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "Lastname", nullable = false)
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "Firstname", nullable = false)
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "Status", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Status status;
}
```

And the enum :

```
package enums;
public enum Status {
    UP,
    DOWN
}
```

And the generated QUser :

```
package models;
import static com.mysema.query.types.PathMetadataFactory.*;
import com.mysema.query.types.path.*;
import com.mysema.query.types.PathMetadata;
import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.mysema.query.types.Path;
/**
 * QUser is a Querydsl query type for User
 */
@Generated("com.mysema.query.codegen.EntitySerializer")
public class QUser extends EntityPathBase<User> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1339629807L;
    public static final QUser user = new QUser("user");
    public final StringPath firstname = createString("firstname");
    public final NumberPath<Integer> id = createNumber("id", Integer.class);
    public final StringPath lastname = createString("lastname");
    public final NumberPath<Status> status = createNumber("status", Status.class);
    public QUser(String variable) {
        super(User.class, forVariable(variable));
    }
    public QUser(Path<? extends User> path) {
        super(path.getType(), path.getMetadata());
    }
    public QUser(PathMetadata<?> metadata) {
        super(User.class, metadata);
    }
}
```

We can see that the field status is wrong generated it should be :
public final EnumPath status = createEnum("status", enums.Status.class);

any idea why the enum is converted numberPath instead enumPath?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Resolved by setting the queryDSLPackage on the root : queryDSLPackage := ""

Comment: Consider making this comment an answer to your question